# React Native: Console Error Can't find variable: task (Image upload and store with Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage

I have followed a [tutorial on uploading photos to Firebase storage using react-native](https://www.instamobile.io/mobile-development/react-native-firebase-storage/) and although it is over a year old and I have had to make a couple of small changes I believe it should still work (for example showImagePicker no longer exists so I replaced it with launchImageLibrary).

This is my UploadScreen.js file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

export default function UploadScreen() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0);

  const selectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      maxWidth: 2000,
      maxHeight: 2000,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = {uri: response?.uri};
        console.log(source);
        setImage(source);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const {uri} = image;
    if (uri) {
      const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      const uploadUri =
        Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
      setUploading(true);
      setTransferred(0);
      const task = storage().ref(filename).putFile(uploadUri);
      // set progress state
      task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
        setTransferred(
          Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000,
        );
      });
    }
    try {
      await task;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setUploading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo uploaded!',
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!',
    );
    setImage('');
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={selectImage}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pick an image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {image !== '' && image !== undefined && (
          <Image source={{uri: image?.uri}} style={styles.imageBox} />
        )}
        {uploading ? (
          <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
            <Progress.Bar progress={transferred} width={300} />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.uploadButton} onPress={uploadImage}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload image</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#bbded6',
  },
  selectButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  selectButton2: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  uploadButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ffb6b9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  progressBarContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  imageBox: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
});
```

When I run this as an ios app on my phone I get this error once pressing the Upload File button:
[image]

which seems to be something to do with this code here...

[image]

I'm not really sure what to do from here as I'm fairly new to React Native so any help with what the error means and how to fix it would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `task` as a local constant to the first block in `uploadImage`, which means that the code in the second block can't find it.

To fix this, I'd pull the `task` up into a function-level variable:

```
  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const {uri} = image;
    let task; //  Add this
    if (uri) {
      const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      const uploadUri =
        Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
      setUploading(true);
      setTransferred(0);
      task = storage().ref(filename).putFile(uploadUri);  //  Remove const here
      // set progress state
      task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
        setTransferred(
          Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000,
        );
      });
    }
    try {
      await task;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
```

Comment: That's brilliant thank you no more error, everything seems to be working as it should except the photo doesn't actually get uploaded to firebase :/